# Neo4j error while importing OSM file (Spatial)

Tags: neo4j, geospatial, spatial

I am trying to use OSM data in graph.db file. I installed 3.1 version of Neo4j. I encounter a strange error when I try this:

BatchInserters.inserter(DB_FILE, config);

DB_FILE contains the absolute file location for graph.db.

Error:

org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.InvalidIdGeneratorException: Sticky generator[ /usr/local/cellar/neo4j/3.1.0/libexec/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id] delete this id file and build a new one

Can someone help me with this one?

I tried to start and clean stop the neo4j server also from command line. Nothing helped.